# Wordforms phrase matching in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx, acronym

Attempting to use Sphinx to build an Acronym library however I am finding that if I for instance make

```
NYC > New York City
```

then I match all of these:

- NYC
- New York City
- I live in New York State but grew up in Kansas City

Which is wholly useless to me. I tried

```
NYC > "New York City"
```

to no avail. Am I correct in assuming that Sphinx is not the engine to do this with?

Answer (score 0):

If you ONLY want phrase matches do

```
New York City > NYC
```